# (Android) Spinner with button and random result?

Tags: android

I'm doing an app in which the idea is that the program gives me one, two, three or four randoms results from a list. I mean, that the user selects how many, for example, flavors, if one, two, three or four and, based on a list of flavors, the program pulls the selected number of randoms. So if I choose two, I get two randoms flavors as a result. If I choose three, three randoms flavors, etc.

The problem is that I do not know how to continue. I'm new to Android and I can not find the answer. Thanks!

This is what I have tried:

```
    Spinner sp;

TextView display_data;

String gustos [] = {"Uno","Dos","Tres","Cuatro"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

Random random = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gustos_aleatorios);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gustos);

    display_data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_result);



    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++){


                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){

                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){

                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){

                    }
                    break;


            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    }


    }
```

}

Comment: you didn't mention what is the problem here, and how the community can help you?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to continue. I'm new to Android and I can not find the answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. when you select for example 2 you should generate 2 random flavors.

So you generate 2 random in a range from 0 to size of the list of flavor :

```
List<String> flavors = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("flavor 1");
    add("flavor 2");
    add("flavor 3");
    add("flavor 4");
    add("flavor 5");
}};
```

then i select 2 so :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
{
    int random = new Random().nextInt(flavors.size()); // generate random between 0 and flavors.size()
    String randomSelectedFlavor = flavors.get(random);
}
```

Comment: @LucianoA.Miracolo Your Welcome

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is each time you need to get n random flavors to first shuffle your list of flavors and then pick the first n flavors. You can create a function like this

```
public static <T> List<T> getRandomSubList(List<T> list, int n) {
    //create a new list if you don't want the original list to get shuffled
    list = new ArrayList<T>(list);
    //shuffle the list
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    //return first n elements of the list
    return list.subList(0, n);
}
```

and the use it like this

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            randomFlavors = getRandomSubList(flavors, 1);        
            break;
        case 1:
            randomFlavors = getRandomSubList(flavors, 2);
            break;
        case 2:
            randomFlavors = getRandomSubList(flavors, 3);
            break;
        case 3:
            randomFlavors = getRandomSubList(flavors, 4);
            break;
    }
}
```

or maybe like this

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    randomFlavors = getRandomSubList(flavors, position + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The accepted answer has a small problem. It might generate the same random number multiple times and thus give you the same flavor multiple times. Do you want that in your app?